# Style can not be found

Tags: android, styling

I am trying to implement my own custom style on my android app, but I can't use this little bit I wrote you can see right here. Why?

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="MyEditText">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimensions/textboxWidth</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimensions/textboxHeight</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">textboxPaddingLeft</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@colors/gray</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The error I get for this is

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'MyEditTextStyle'

Answer (score 1):

Please make the following change from:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="MyEditText">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: So I have to apply my custom style for all `textView`s of my App?

Comment: Depends on what you want it for. For example if you want it only for the text in your actionbar, you can:   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item> and then have <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyleTheme</item>
    </style>